# How to pass custom values from buildForm() to submitForm()

Tags: 8, forms

My `buildForm()` method queries the database and returns data which is used to calculate default values for the form. How can I use these values in `submitForm()` without querying the database again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, the `$form_state` object can be used to stash that data. `$form_state->getStorage()` references a simple array that you can put whatever you like inside, which you can then retrieve in `submitForm()` the same way.

You can store values in `buildForm` function as follows

```
$form_state->set('variable_name', $value);
```

Inside `submitForm` function, you can retrieve this as

```
$value = $form_state->get('variable_name');
```

`variable_name` can be any name

Comment: Specifically, use $form_state->get()/$form_state->set() to set and access these values.